# CSS column-count bug

Tags: css

I am trying to use CSS column-count property. My current HTML structure consist of a parent '**div**' with inner '**p**' tag and I applied **column-count: 3** to the div and it works fine. But for certain break points column count showing is 2 instead of 3.  Can any one explain why count changes for certain break points and how content is divided in each column?

```
HTML
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod 
     voluptatum nemo illum, numquam aperiam minus sit cumque 
     perspiciatis dicta, molestiae inventore reiciendis aut, officiis 
     nobis deserunt provident commodi sunt aliquam!</p>
</div>

 CSS
 .wrapper {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; 
    -moz-column-count: 3; 
    column-count: 3;
  }
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes. How can we help you if you don't share code that replicates the problem your are describing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column layout exhibits the following default behavior (on Chrome 67):

1. Regardless of the `column-count` setting, columns won't be wrapped unless they have at least 2 lines, except if ...
2. ... typesetting this way would result in at max half of the columns being used.

You can control the way columns get filled by specifying the CSS properties [`orphans`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/orphans) and [`widows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/widows) which specify the minimum number of lines a block container must show at the top or the bottom of a column, respectively.

A value of `1` allows for height balancing in columns even for text that would only span a single line.

Setting the value to an integer `n` means that all used columns but the last one must contain at least `n` lines of text. The default value is `2` for both properties.

Successively increasing the integer values leads to successively fewer layout columns used for any given text.

**Demo**

I've tried to set up a reproducible test setting container dimensions and font-sizes. As is it covers 6 columns. Removing any of the CSS properties 'orphans' or 'widows' causes layout in 3 columns only.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS column  count demo</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .wrapper {
                border: solid 1px black;
                font-family: Times New Roman;
                font-size: 12pt;
                width: 800px;
                height: 400px;
            }
            .wrapper p {
                column-count: 6;
                orphans: 1;
                widows:  1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
             The following text covers 6 columns.
             Removing any of the CSS properties 'orphans' or 'widows' causes layout in 3 columns only.
        -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod 
             voluptatum nemo illum, numq</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase your data it will show in 3 columns. If data is not there how it can be split in 3 columns. You have to put enough data so that data under P tag will split in 3 columns.